# Interface definition for platform-specific behavior

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, interface

I'm converting an old editor type application from WinForms to WPF. It has some tools (like the kind in Photoshop) where you select them, they have some behavior, and they have a cursor icon.

I've got my domain logic separated into a BLL, so there's an interface for tool behavior there along with a few implementations that aren't WPF dependent. I'm trying to figure out how to implement cursor behavior while not tying the BLL to WPF.

It seems like everything to do with drawing is platform specific - the drawing contexts, the images, etc. which means that there are no possible methods or parameter types that I could put in an interface in the BLL. I don't plan on actually using WinForms again, and I have no other platforms planned in the future, but I want to write this code well as if that were a possibility.

Sample code: I have in the BLL this interface:

```
public interface IToolProvider
{
    IToolBehavior Tool { get; }
}
```

and then this:

```
public interface IToolBehavior
{
    void Click(ScreenDocument screen, Point location);
    void Move(ScreenDocument screen, Point location);
    void Release(ScreenDocument screen);
    void RightClick(ScreenDocument screen, Point location);
}
```

(I'm using my own implementation of `Point` here, basically due to this exact problem that every platform has their own Point class.)

I want to add something like `IToolCursor Cursor { get; }` to the `IToolProvider` interface, but I have no idea what would go in the `IToolCursor` interface that could work simultaneously with WPF and other platforms.